# How to process multiple html form values in php

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I'm doing a survey form in php. For each question there are 3 answer options, only 1 can be selected, so doing radio buttons for input values with the same name. I believe I am using an array for these values unless I botched the syntax.

How do I load these selected values using POST form values, per question, in to my sql db answers table?

A simple iteration over this POST form array outputs nothing, so what am I missing?

Thanks!

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
   echo '<p>'.sprintf($row['question'],$partner_name);
   echo 'Yes<input type="radio" id="'.$row['question_id'].'" name="'.$row['question_id'].'[]" value="Yes">';
   echo 'Maybe<input type="radio" id="'.$row['question_id'].'" name="'.$row['question_id'].'[]" value="Maybe">';
   echo 'No<input type="radio" id="'.$row['question_id'].'" name="'.$row['question_id'].'[]" value="No">';
   echo '</p>';
}
```

Comment: ur array name must not start with number. just append any letter before $row['question_id']. also, ID must be unique in the same HTML page

Comment: Are you sure you're submitting the form via POST? The name can also start with a number so you don't need to worry about that.